# Generics in Typescript 1.8.2

Tags: generics, typescript

The following piece of code is highlighted with this error:

> Cannot find name TEntity

```
createEntity<TEntity>() : Promise<TEntity> {                      
    let type = typeof(TEntity);
}
```

How can I use `TEntity` inside the function?

Answer (score 2):

You can archive something similar to what you want by using this approach:

```
class Car
{
    public name: string;    
}

function createEntity<T>(type:{new ():T}): T 
{
    console.log(type);

    let c = new Car();
    console.log(c instanceof type);

    return new type();
}

console.log(createEntity<Car>(Car));
```

Comment: I will try it shortly. Thanks!

Comment: It's not exactly what I had in mind though.
The constructors for each one of the types could be different, hence the factory method's signature could be different as well. I want to get the type  , then invoke correspondent constructor according to that type (the ctor might have mandatory parameters, etc.). is this possible in JS/TS? @Amid